# Как реализовать систему диалогов в текстовой РПГ android?

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Пишу текстовую РПГ-игру для *Android*, в которой игроку нужно будет выбирать из 2-3 вариантов развития сюжета, от выбора зависит дальнейшее развитие сюжета (типичное РПГ, да). Подскажите, как реализовать саму систему выбора? Была идея построить на *SQLite*, но это не выход, я так понимаю. Еще читал про `.xml` файлы с узлами, которые подгружаются при определенном действии.

А какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: для удобства простоты и скорости разработки рекомендую Room

Comment: @SviatVolkov а можно ссылочку на этот продукт или плагин, не могу нагуглить?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQLite` в этом случае достаточно. Другие `СУБД` так же можно использовать.

Столбцы первой таблицы (Questions):

```
id, text
```

Столбцы второй таблицы(Answers):

```
id, text, question_id, next_question_id
```

Думаю по таблицам все ясно, что в первой хранятся вопросы, а во второй ответы и связи с другими вопросами(`question_id` - к какому вопросу относится ответ, `next_question_id` - идентификатор следующего вопроса)